# Dynamically created nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to dynamically create a nested array in javascript. The array needs to have this structure.

```
{
  "name": "main",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "main_topic_1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "sub_topic",
          "size": 422
        },
        {
          "name": "sub_topic",
          "size": 422
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "main_topic_2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "sub_topic",
          "size": 422
        },
        {
          "name": "sub_topic",
          "size": 422
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "main_topic_3",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "sub_topic",
          "size": 422
        },
        {
          "name": "sub_topic",
          "size": 422
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to be able to dynamically choose the number of "main_topic_x" as well as the number of sub_topics that belong to those respective main_topics.

I am trying something like this, but I don't know how to get the structure as above.

```js
main_topics = ['topic 1','topic 2','topic 3'];
    sub_topics = ['subtopic 1','subtopic 2'];

    var a = new Array();
    var b = new Array();

    for(l=0; l<main_topics.length; l++){
      a[l] = b;
      for(j=0; j<sub_topics.length; j++){
        b[l] = sub_topics[j];
      }
    }
  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2));
```

Comment: Why do elements of `main_topics` and `sub_topics` include space character in string? Where are `name` and `size` properties populated in objects?

Comment: You again? lol With the structure as you have it, you will have to iterate over the entire object to look for the key. If the structure doesn't have to be like that, I'd recommend restructuring it using what you want as a key so you can reference it easier.

Comment: Unfortunately the structure has to be like this since it is feeding a D3 visualization. I just need to be able to dynamically set the number of topics and subtopics; I know how to name them now.

Comment: I'm pretty adept at d3. If you explain which visualization and what you're trying to do I might be able to help you a little more.

Comment: What i'd probably do is add another variable to the structure like "active" or something of that sort to each level, that way you can reference it in the d3 code that powers your visualization.

Comment: It's the tree layout in D3...the expandable one that uses the flare.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I put together for you:

```
var JSON_Object = {name:"main", children:[]};
var main_topics = ["main_topic_1", "main_topic_2", "main_topic_3","main_topic_4"];
var sub_topics = [  {parent_topic:0, name:"sub_topic_1", size:422},
                    {parent_topic:0, name:"sub_topic_2", size:422},
                    {parent_topic:0, name:"sub_topic_3", size:212},
                    {parent_topic:1, name:"sub_topic_4", size:322},
                    {parent_topic:1, name:"sub_topic_5", size:422},
                    {parent_topic:2, name:"sub_topic_6", size:322},
                    {parent_topic:2, name:"sub_topic_7", size:125},
                    {parent_topic:3, name:"sub_topic_8", size:422}];
for (let i in main_topics) {
  let tempObj = {name:main_topics[i], children:[]};
  for (let j in sub_topics) {
    if (sub_topics[j].parent_topic==i) {
      tempObj.children.push({name:sub_topics[j].name,size:sub_topics[j].size});
    }
  }
  JSON_Object.children.push(tempObj);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON_Object, null, 2));
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I had to make a slight change to handle dynamically changing number of sub_topics but it works great. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way to produce a dynamic data structure is to start by producing the output structure, and transform the input structures inline, like this:

```
var output = {
  name: 'main',
  children: main_topics.map(topic => ({
    name: topic,
    children: sub_topics.map(subTopic => ({
      name: subTopic,
      size: 422
    })
  })
};
```

It's not clear where you're expecting to get `size` from or why the names in your sample output don't match what's in `main_topics` or `sub_topics`, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't see how the subtopics can be different for each topic thought. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Your source data is just an array of sub-topic names; it's not clear where you're wanting to get those different subtopics from. If you have a different source of data, you should add to the question.